# How to make a tar backup of a root filesystem?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, disk-partitioning, rootfs

I have linux installed on SD card, I used this command to install the rootfs

tar xpjf rootfs.tar.bz -C /mnt/rootfs/

Now, I made some changes to the rootfs and I would like to create a backup that I can use with the same command above, I tried using:

```
tar cpjf rootfs.tar.bz2 /mnt/rootfs
and
tar cpjf rootfs.tar.bz2 -C / mnt/rootfs
I also tried
tar cpjf rootfs.tar.bz2 /mnt/rootfs/*
```

And tried:

```
cd /mnt/rootfs
tar -cvpjf rootfs.tar.bz2 --exclude=/rootfs.tar.bz2 .
tar: ./rootfs.tar.bz2: file changed as we read it
```

but I end up with an archive that has two levels before the file system i.e mnt/rootfs/files What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: well answered here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem/TAR

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That's because it starts from current working directory, you can do:

```
cd /mnt/rootfs
tar cpjf /rootfs.tar.bz2 .
```

And that should create an archive at /rootfs.tar.bz2 with its root at the contents of /mnt/rootfs/

Comment: Don't use `*`. That might fail with files named like "--filename". Instead, use `./*` .

Comment: Also, it might be worth noting that `./*` (and `*`) might not pick up files whose names begin with a dot.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, i used * as the user posted the question with that, corrected the answer ;)

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak so how do I include hidden files ?

Comment: @mux `tar cjpf /rootfs.tar.bz2 .`

Comment: @mux the alternative is stuff like `./* ./.*` which you may notice doesn't work quire right, because `./.*` will include `.` and `..`. Another problem with wildcards (`./*`) is that if there's nothing in the folder at all, it will not expand, and tar will try to pack a file named `./*`, which does not exist.

Comment: Thank you all, I just tried installing from the backup and it boots fine.

Comment: @alex88 you really should change that to a dot, its the only solution that just works right in all cases

Comment: @AmbrozBizjak I will make another backup just in case, but, just to be clear, the right way to include everything (including hidden files) is 
tar cjpf /rootfs.tar.bz2 .  right ?

Comment: `tar cpjf /rootfs.tar.bz2  -C /mnt/rootfs .`  Where `-C` means "cd into <path> then ...."    Is simpler.